# MethodNotAllowedHttpException laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new in laravel. 
I'm getting this Error when i click update.

```
<form  method="post" action="{{ route('companies.update',[$company->id]) }}">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input type="hidden" name="method" value="put">
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxMxh.png)

Comment: Please show related route definition.

Comment: my first impression is that the route is not defined in your web.php

Comment: Is your route `Route::get()` or `Route::post()`? That's usually the first thing to check when you get a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`, so including your `routes.php` or `routes/web.php` would be *very* beneficial to getting this questions answered.

Comment: Thanks For quick your response. 
I got my solution by adding this 
 "illuminate/html": "~5.0" in Composer.json 
'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
to my app.php "aliases"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That time i was a newbie in laravel. the problem was calling name route without define them.
Example-1: `Route::get('something')->name('some')`
so now i can call it from anywhere like `route('some')`
Example-2: `Route::get('something')`
in this case you can use `url('something')` or `href="something"`
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Update your `name="method"` to `name="_method"`

So

`<input type="hidden" name="method" value="put">`

should be

`<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">`

You can also use a helper to generate the input `{{ method_field('PUT') }}`

You can look about it in the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#form-method-spoofing).

Comment: Thanks For quick your response. 
I got my solution by adding this 
 "illuminate/html": "~5.0" in Composer.json 
'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
to my app.php "aliases"